# Help on Inserting a record to the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to insert a record into my db based on the values of querystring parameters, at the minute I just have the scaffold methods and it works, it takes the values at the in the new method, then when the sumbit button is clicked, it is inserted into the db.

How can I 'skip' the clicking of the button, so it is inserted just in the new method?

Code:

```
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
@book = Book.new({:user_id=>session[:user_id], :author=>session['test']})

respond_to do |format|
  if @book.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@book, :notice => 'Book was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @book, :status => :created, :location => @book }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @book.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: You want to modify the database in the new action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the action which you want to do a save automatically:

```
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
@book.save
```

Some thing you might want to add: Only save if if params[:book] is set:

```
unless params[:book].blank?
  @book = Book.new(params[:book])
  @book.save
end
```

Also think of error handling. What if the book could not be stored?